Entity print with DomPDF doesn't work on Pantheon
I have a Drupal 9.3 site with PHP 7.4 that is hosted on Pantheon where I am using Entity print module with the DomPDF. The entity print does work perfectly locally that uses Lando but it's not working on the Pantheon and it throws the following error and file is available in the file system.

Error generating document: Failed to generate PDF: Error loading /sites/default/files/2024-07/example-image-name.jpg: Permission denied. The file could not be found under the paths specified by Options::chroot. /sites/default/files/2024-07/example-image-name.jpg

I have already spent couple of hours on it but couldn't find a way. Moreover, I've found a Pentheon documentation page File system that might help but not sure how to make it work. Any idea about how can I fix it on the Pantheon environment?

Contact Pantheon support? DomPDF is not on their list of incompatible modules, but maybe it should be.
